# Transferring Props to Multi-Level Upward in React Child-Parent Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 3 React components with such relationship:

1. Parent
2. Child
3. ChildofChild

I want to have a button in `ChildofChild` component, when clicked to update state in `Parent` component. I can send it to `Child` component via props and run a fuction there.

**ChildOfChild**

```
// ChildOfChild Component
export class PlaceInfoWindow extends Component {

  render() {
    const {description, name, price} = this.props

    return(
      <InfoWindow onCloseClick={this.props.closeWindow}>
        <div>
          <h1>{name}</h1>
          <p>{description}</p>
          <span>${price}</span>
          <button type="button" onClick={this.props.onAdd} className="btn btn-primary btn-success m-2">Add</button>
        </div>
      </InfoWindow>
    );
  }
}

export default PlaceInfoWindow
```

**Child**

```
//Child Component
    export class PlaceMarker extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          showTooltip: false,
        };
      }

      clickTooltip() {
        this.setState({ showTooltip: !this.state.showTooltip });
      }

      closeWindow() {
        this.setState({ showTooltip: false });
      }

       render() {
        const { showTooltip } = this.state;
        const { lat, lng, name, price, description } = this.props;

        return (
          <Marker
            position={{
              lat: parseFloat(lat),
              lng: parseFloat(lng)
            }}
            onClick={this.clickTooltip.bind(this)}
            icon="https://image.ibb.co/cGPSW8/red_marker.png"
          >
            {showTooltip && (
              <PlaceInfoWindow
                description={description}
                name={name}
                price={price}
                closeWindow={this.closeWindow.bind(this)}
                onAdd={this.props.onAdd}
              />
            )}
          </Marker>
        );
      }
    }

    export default PlaceMarker;
```

**Parent**

```
// Parent Component
const AirbnbMap = withGoogleMap(props => (
  <GoogleMap
    defaultCenter={props.center}
    defaultZoom={props.zoom}
    defaultOptions={{
      styles: userMapStyle
    }}
  >
    {props.places.length > 0 &&
      props.places.map(place => (
        <PlaceMarker
          key={`place${place.id}`}
          id={place.id}
          lat={place.latitude}
          lng={place.longitude}
          description={place.description}
          name={place.name}
          price={place.price}
          onAdd={this.handleAdd}
        />
      ))}
  </GoogleMap>
));

export class Map extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.zoom = 7;

    this.state = {
      lat: 50.0515918,
      lng: 19.9357531,
      places: [       
        {
        id: 1,
        latitude: 50,
        longitude: 20,
        description: "ABC",
        name: "City",
        price: 20
      }]
    };
  }


  handleAdd = () => {
    console.log("handle add called");
  };

  render() {
    const { lat, lng, places } = this.state;
    console.log(places);
    return (
      <div style={{ width: `100%`, height: `750px` }}>
        <AirbnbMap
          center={{
            lat: lat,
            lng: lng
          }}
          places={places}
          zoom={this.zoom}
          containerElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
          mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Map;
```

But how can I send it to `Parent`(two levels up) component? In this way, `Child` component will only forward the props to the `Parent` component, which it took from its child (`ChildofChild`).

Comment: I recommend reading through the React docs on lifting state up: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: If using React 16 you can try the new Context API.

Comment: @Dez Just to forward a handler? This is not exactly the use case for the context API and only adding an unnecessary layer complexity.

Comment: @trixn I disagree. Context API is useful to share data between different levels. In this case you have an intermediate level (`Children`) where you are not going to need the handler. You are just sending the handler to it because you need it downwards. Context API is useful for global state management and events are used to change the state of the application.

Comment: @Dez What is the problem in just passing it down if the intermediate component does not need that handler? This is a more than common pattern in react and the context api is not the preferred solution to it. There is no reason to assume the handler OP is referring to has any app global character so the context api is overkill for it. Also see [Before You Use Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#before-you-use-context) in the official react docs.

Comment: @trixn Tight coupling between components, maintainability, ... For example, Redux was created to avoid the problems of having to pass down through many components props that were going to not be used by the intermediate components. The new Context API is designed so you are not going to need an application state management such Redux in all cases.

Comment: @Dez But it was also not designed to just avoid passing a handler down via multiple levels (which is required often). Please read [Before You Use Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#before-you-use-context) from the react docs. There is no indication OPs example meets the recommended criteria when to use the context API. The handler is local to these three components and can easily just be forwarded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your top Parent component is not AirbnbMap, is class Map. Also you are declaring handleAdd in your Map class, but your are not passing it to Airbnb component. On Map you should pass it on :

```
<AirbnbMap handleAdd={this.handleAdd}
    // Rest of props here
    />
```

Then on AirbnbMap class:

```
<PlaceMarker 
    ...
    onAdd={props.handleAdd} 
    />
```

The rest looks ok.

Comment: I have tried your solution, but not worked for me. I've added the full components up, could you have a look?

Comment: This worked, Thank you! I used {props.handleAdd} instead of {this.props.handleAdd} as it already takes props as an arg.

Answer (score 3):

It's no problem to just forward props. This includes handlers:

```
class Parent extends Component {
    handle = event => { /* handle event */ };

    render() {
        return (
            <Child handler={this.handle} />
        );
    } 
}

const Child = ({handler}) => (
    <ChildOfChild handler={handler} />
);

const ChildOfChild = ({handler}) => (
    <button onClick={handler}>Click me!</button>
);
```

Comment: been searching for 2 days for simple explanation, this one saved me. thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

From React 16.3 on, you could use the new [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext) so you don't need to pass down the props to every children and be able to lift up state easily and cleanly.

```
import React, { Component, createContext } from 'react';

const ParentContext = createContext({});

class Parent extends Component {
    handle = event => { console.log('Event', event) };

    render() {
        return (
          <ParentContext.Provider value={{
            onClick: this.handle,
          }}>
            <Child />
          </ParentContext.Provider>
        );
    } 
}

const Child = () => (<ChildOfChild />);

const ChildOfChild = () => ( 
  <ParentContext.Consumer>
    { (context) => <button onClick={context.onClick}>Click me!</button>}
  </ParentContext.Consumer>
);

export default Parent;
```